# How to allocate a struct of struct?

Tags: c, malloc

So, I have a struct inside of other struct.. and I whant to know how I can malloc that struct...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct 
{
    int n, o, p;
    struct
    {
        int a, b, c;
    }Str2;
}Str1;

main()
{
   struct Str1.Str2 *x (Str1.Str2*)malloc(sizeof(struct Str1.Str2*));

   x->a = 10;
}
```

So, I try that, but, not work..
How I can make this, Or is more better allocate all struct ?

Answer (score 3):

You just need to allocate Str1 and Str2 would be allocated automatically. On my system, the sizeof for Str1 is 24 which equals to the size of 6 ints. Try this:

```
typedef struct {
int n;
int o;
int p;
struct {
      int a;
      int b;
      int c;
      }Str2;
}Str1;

main()
{
     Str1 *x = (Str1 *)malloc(sizeof(Str1));
     x->Str2.a = 10;
     printf("sizeof(Str1) %d\n", (int)sizeof(Str1));
     printf("value of a: %d\n", x->Str2.a);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not declare things like:

```
typedef struct
{
    int a, b, c;
}Str2;

typedef struct 
{
    int n, o, p;
    Str2 s2;
}Str1;
```

Then you can allocate them individually as you desire.  For instance:

```
Str2 *str2 = (Str2*)malloc(sizeof(Str2));
Str1 *str1 = (Str1*)malloc(sizeof(Str1));
s1->s2.a = 0; // assign 0 to the a member of the inner Str2 of str1.
```

Comment: Ooook, and to use this ?? .. 
    struct Str1 *x = (struct Str1*)malloc(sizeof(struct Str1*)); and x->s2.a = 10 ?

Answer (score 1):

`Str1` and `Str2` are objects of the anonymous `struct`s you declared, so the syntax is way off. Did you forget some typedefs?

```
//declares a single object Str1 of an anonymous struct
struct 
{
}Str1;

//defines a new type - struct Str1Type
typedef struct
{
}Str1Type;
```

Answer (score 1):

To name a `struct`, you use

```
 struct Str1
 {
    ... 
 };
```

You can now use `struct Str1` when you want to refer to this particular `struct`.

If you want to use it as `Str1` only, you need to use `typedef`, e.g.

```
typedef struct tagStr1
{
  ...
} Str1;
```

Or `typedef struct Str1 Str1;` if we have the first type of `struct Str1` declaration.

To create an instance of a `struct` with no name (Instance means "a variable of that type"):

```
 struct
 {
   ...
 } Instance;
```

Since this `struct` doesn't have a name, it can't be used anywhere else, which is generally not what you want.

In C (as opposed to C++) you can not define a new type structure inside another the type definition of another structure, so

```
typedef struct tagStr1
{
    int a, b, c;
    typedef struct tagStr2
    {
       int x, y, z;
    } Str2;
} Str1;
```

will not compile.

If we change the code to this:

```
typedef struct tagStr1
{
    int a, b, c;
    struct tagStr2
    {
       int x, y, z;
    };
} Str1;
typedef struct tagStr2 Str2;
```

will compile - but at least gcc gives a warning for "struct tagStr2 does not declare anythign" (because it expects you wanted to actually have a member of type `struct tagStr2` inside `Str1`.

Comment: oook, and to use:

struct Str2 *x = (struct Str2*)malloc(sizeof(struct Str2*));

x->x = 10;

Comment: Not `sizeof(struct Str2*)` - that makes space for only a pointer. `sizeof(struct Str2);`